# CSV to Output an Array that contains a field with JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2 and I want to import a CSV and store the records in the database. Name, Surname and Contact Number will be core fields and anything else will just be additional data that I want to store as JSON in an additional info field

example

```
* | name | surname | contact_number | gender | race |"
* | piet | pokol   | 0111111111     | male   | race |"
```

will be stored like so:

```
* ['name'=>'piet','surname'=>'pokol', 'contact_number'=>'0111111111', 'additional_data'=>'{gender:"male", race:"green"}']
```

My question is,is it possible to combine an array with JSON array like this?

So far I have it working to make a traditional array with this code

```
foreach ($reader as $index => $row) {

                if ($index === 0) {
                    $headers = $row;
                } else {


                    $data = array_combine($headers, $row);

                    $array = array_merge($data, ['client_id' => $client_id, 'list_id' => $list_id]);

                    Customer::create($array);

                }

            }
```

But I need to JSON encode all the field that are not core fields and then add them to the array.

Any body have any advice on this?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. You can store json encoded array as value in other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code, it might help you. You can use result array to store in database.

```
<?php
$data = array(
                'name'=> "My Name",
                'surname'=> 'My Surname',
                'contact_number'=> '0987456321',
                'age'=> '38',
                'gender'=> 'female',
                'address'=> 'NewYork, USA',
                );

$core = array('name','surname','contact_number');
$result = array();
$additional = array();

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    if(in_array($key, $core)) {
        $result[$key] = $val;
    } else {
        $additional[$key]= $val;
    }
}

if(count($additional)) {
    $result['additional'] = json_encode($additional);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
?>
```